# Why does Typescript let me return a non-void value in a function that should return void

Tags: typescript

I have this class declaration:

```js
class Event {
    action: () => void;

    constructor(identifier: string, action: () => void) {
        (...)
    }
}
```

Typescript then lets me construct an object from that class with an `action` parameter function that does not return void without error, for example:

```js
const newObject = new Event("string", () => {
    return "string";
});
```

However, if I change the return type of the parameter function `action` to `string` in the class declaration for example, and then construct an object whose parameter `action` returns a number, it does show the expected error:

```
Argument of type '() => number' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => string'.
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Comment: Some portions of code were removed for better readability but let me know if you need me to put something else up

Comment: [TypeScript FAQ: Why are functions returning non-`void` assignable to function returning `void`?](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-returning-non-void-assignable-to-function-returning-void)

Comment: Because returning something when nothing is expected does no harm, but returning the wrong thing when something is expected does harm.  There's no compelling reason to perform checks to prevent the former.

Comment: Well, that looks easy enough to find, I have to improve my googling skills, thank you, how do I mark this as answered?